# Can't import STL file into gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, stl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I can't seem to create STL files that gazebo will accept. I have tried exporting stl files from Autodesk Inventor 2012, Solidworks 2011 and Pro/Engineer wildfire 5.0. For testing purposes I have been exporting a simple rectangular prism and using the spinning top tutorial. If it is helpful I can upload the .stl files I was using. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance
Brian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11859/can%27t-import-stl-file-into-gazebo/) by [brian axelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/1341/brian-axelrod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a [ticket](http://https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4740) floating around regarding how to potentially resolve your issue.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0